# Selenium TimeoutException: Message:

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I have the following code which scrapes questions from stack overflow. When i used `class names` as `css selectors` for ex: `question-hyperlink` is class name and i converted it to css selector as `.question-hyperlink`. It works fine with that.

But when i used `tagNames` as `CSS selectors` like `.A` or `.DIV`, It returns me this timeout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\D_scraper2.pyw", line 37, in to_do
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

**My code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

def to_do():
# vars...
    csv_file_location = r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\data_file.csv"

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                 'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'

    driver_exe = 'chromedriver'
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    options.add_argument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt")

    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\setups\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    driver.get(url)

    one_ = ".A"

    two_ = ".DIV"

    three_ = ".A"

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, one_))
        )
        elements_1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(one_)

        web_content_list = []
        for ele in elements_1:
            web_content_dict = {}
            web_content_dict["Title"] = ele.text
            web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, two_))
        )
        elements_2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(two_)

        for ele2 in elements_2:
            web_content_dict = {}
            web_content_dict["Title2"] = ele2.text
            web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, three_))
        )

        elements_3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(three_)

        for ele3 in elements_3:
            web_content_dict = {}
            web_content_dict["Title3"] = ele3.text
            web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

        df = pd.DataFrame(web_content_list)
        new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': df['Title'].dropna(),
                  'Column 2': df['Title2'].dropna(),
                  'Column 3': df['Title3'].dropna()})
        new_df.to_csv(csv_file_location,
                  index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')

        try:
            f = open(csv_file_location)
            print("Done !!!\n"*3)

        except IOError:
            print("File not accessible")

        finally:
            f.close()
        driver.quit()

    except:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, one_))
        )
        elements_1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(one_)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, two_))
        )

        elements_2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(two_)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, three_))
        )

        elements_3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(three_)

        df = pd.DataFrame({
            "Title1" : [ele for ele.text in elements_1],
            "Title2" : [ele2 for ele2.text in elements_2],
            "Title3" : [ele3 for ele3.text in elements_3],
        })
        df.to_csv(csv_file_location,
                  index=False, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')

        try:
            f = open(csv_file_location)
            print("Done !!!\n"*3)
            # Do something with the file
        except IOError:
            print("File not accessible")

        finally:
            f.close()
        driver.quit()

    finally:
        print("start")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_do()
```

> In the case of `class names` as `css selectors`, i used three columns in the csv files, and in the case of `tagNames` as well, i am using three columns to csv. Maybe there are more of columns in those tags...

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to search a tag using css selector, you don't use the period in front of it.  If you wanted to use the 'a' anchor tag, you would do it like below:

```
one_ = "a"

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, one_))
        )
```

Placing the dot in front is used for class names.

Comment: Thanks @RKelley it worked well. However the csv file has too much spaces between them. And it also has scraped everything which is not needed. How to limit that? For example, if i want to get just questions in h1 tag and not the stackoverflow website name in the h1 tag

Comment: I just saw this after I answered your same question posted elsewhere.  To limit to the questions, you should change one_ to '#questions h3 a'.  What this will do is search for the id of 'questions' and then look for any child h3 elements with a child anchor ('a') tag.